# How can I apply reflection texture to a material?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have made a **[Kit Previewer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YgqT_xd_oo_-oF3zdkTxnZ4pYtiRJm4A/view?usp=sharing)** for **FIFA20**, which will be used by those who make **unofficial patches** for this **game**. A **player model** is projected through Blender, which wear a **team jersey** etc, so if someone wants to **make** a new **team kit** for a team, will be able to test it into Blender before throwing it into the game.

I have **managed** with some tools to **extract** the necessary **meshes** from the game to **obj** format and **import** them into **Blender**. Also I have create a **material** and I have applied the **[color texture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iVVm35QB8VF-BxX3IcqfI3agmy8Joa0h/view?usp=sharing)** and the **[normal texture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xifSamp74aUUAnW911qJSc8H90FbwGZb/view?usp=sharing)**.

What I find **difficult** to apply in Blender, is the **[coeff texture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15S0FIxXhajrRoEQJ-k1oRfWlQPdA-MrW/view?usp=sharing)**, which based on **[this](https://soccergaming.com/index.php?threads/riesscars-kit-coeff-creation-tutorial-ii-colors-and-reflection.6467830/)** tutorial, defines in the game, apart from the type of fabric (which we are not interested in at the moment) and the gloss!!! As mentioned in the tutorial, red is less reflective, brown is almost reflective, pink/purple is more reflective and cyan is very reflective.

So the question is, how can I apply something like this to a Blender material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like blue and green together are being used to affect reflectiveness, which is why cyan gives the strongest effect - in any case it seems like red is not used for shininess purposes, so Separate RGB can be used to grab the other two channels.

You could use a ColorRamp to adjust the strength of the effect before sending it the material, I guess by reducing the roughness and maybe increasing the metallicity. I suspect that the green and blue channels might be used to control two different aspects of the material but you might just have to play around until you find something that looks decent.

I've updated my [Example .blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/e12977b7bd28459689feff18e6f2c235) to send the result of adding blue+green to Metallic, and then inverted it before sending it to Roughness (so cyan is inverted to black, making it 0 roughness).

[image: Node graph]

Comment: Hello Nick and thank you for your answer and your time! I think red has to do with the kind of fabric and as you said, green and blue together give specific colors which define the strength of reflection. Your solution sounds logic but I lost you after "Seperate RGB"!!! What is this "Add" table?

Comment: Hey @SimonetosTheGreek, I've just linked to my updated .blend file where I've connected the green+blue result to Roughness and Metallic. Once it's attached to your kit model the ColorRamp sliders and the Invert factor slider can be adjusted until the shininess looks right.